# It's possible to convert a string to uppercase excluding certain words in Swift?

Tags: string, swift

I would like to convert a string to Title case but excluding some words that don't need to be changed, as names of products, services and other trademark names.

With this code:

```
var storyTtitle = "Presented the new PowerBook"
let newStr = str.capitalizedStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
```

The result here is: "Presented The New Powerbook", unfortunately changing the word "Powerbook", in this case, it's a mistake. Does anyone know if there is a way to exclude some words, maybe contained in a list?

Comment: Do you really want an exclude list, or do you want to capitalize only the initial character, while leaving the remaining characters unchanged?

Comment: Hi maddy, I thought about it and if possible would be nice not to use the exclude list. Then bringing further forward your reasoning, perhaps there would be this way to go without using it: the words that already contain a capital letter (eg iPhone, OS X, Xcode, MacBook, iOS) are not changed, while all words that do not contain any capital letter are subject to possible change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerateSubstringsInRange()` with the `.ByWords`
options to enumerate all words in a string. This has the advantage
that it works correctly even if a word is not delimited by
space characters.

Your idea from above comment

> the words that already contain a capital letter (eg iPhone, OS X, Xcode, MacBook, iOS) are not changed, while all words that do not contain any capital letter are subject to possible change

can then be implemented like this:

```
let storyTtitle = "Presented 'the' new PowerBook!  (or iPhone?)"

var newTitle = storyTtitle
var offset = 0
storyTtitle.enumerateSubstringsInRange(storyTtitle.characters.indices, options: .ByWords) {
    (substring, substringRange, _, _) in
    if let oldString = substring where oldString == oldString.lowercaseString {
        let range = substringRange.startIndex.advancedBy(offset) ..< substringRange.endIndex.advancedBy(offset)
        let newString = oldString.capitalizedString
        newTitle.replaceRange(range, with: newString)
        offset += newString.characters.count - oldString.characters.count
    }
}

print(newTitle)
// Presented 'The' New PowerBook!  (Or iPhone?)
```

The `offset` variable and the "complicated" range calculations are
necessary because the uppercase version of a string does not 
necessarily have the same number of characters as the lowercase version.
For example, in German, the uppercase string for `"ß"` is `"SS"`.

Comment: Truly brilliant Martin

Comment: I noticed a small annoyance: "1970s" becomes "1970S", do you think that there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: @Tel: Good point. Unfortunately, I don't have a good idea at present.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps. There are a few different functions for capitalizing strings. I think this is what you wanted.

```
var storyTtitle: String = "Presented the new PowerBook"
var newStr: String = ""

var listToExclude: [String] = ["PowerBook"]

var stringArray: [String] = storyTtitle.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

for str in stringArray {
    for excludeStr in listToExclude {
        if !str.containsString(excludeStr) {
            newStr.appendContentsOf(str.localizedCapitalizedString)
            if str != stringArray.last {
                newStr.appendContentsOf(" ")
            }
        }
    }
}
print(newStr)
```

Comment: Mm, it's not exactly the same. Capitalizing a *String* which can contain many words, and doing it according to the locale, is not the same as just capitalizing single words.

Comment: Thank you Sethmr. Unfortunately your code prints "Presented The New", actually it should get: "Presented The New PowerBook".

Comment: That's because PowerBook was in my list of words to exclude for the point of the example.

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it. Thank you.